# ASP .NET MVC + LINQ Generated Classes + DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, data-annotations

I have a problem, and i hope, u can help me with it. Ok, i'll try to describe my situation:

I've created database.
Added table "Orders".
Then generated LINQ Classes in dbml file.

Now, i have create action in controller, and i'm trying to set [DisplayName("Other name")] for one or my Order class property (Client name). So, look at this:

**/ Core / Extansions.cs**

```
namespace SUPNew.Core
{
    public static class Extansions
    {

    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(OrderMetaData))]
    public partial class Order
    {
    }

    public class OrderMetaData
    {
        [DisplayName("ФИО клиента")]
        public string ClientFIO { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**/ Views / Manager / AddOrder.aspx**

```
    <legend>Fields</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientFIO) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientFIO) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientFIO) %>
    </div>
```

**/ Controllers / ManagerController.cs**

```
using SUPNew.Core;
```

**/ Models / SUPNew.dbml**

```
    public partial class Order : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
...
        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ClientFIO", DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string ClientFIO
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ClientFIO;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._ClientFIO != value))
                {
                    this.OnClientFIOChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._ClientFIO = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("ClientFIO");
                    this.OnClientFIOChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

So, maybe i forgot to make something? I need to display DisplayName for ClientFIO in LabelFor(model => model.ClientFIO) that i've choosen in partial class.

Thx for help.

---

If i change .dbml file- adding [DisplayName("OtherName")] like this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ClientFIO", DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
[DisplayName("Other name")]            
public string ClientFIO
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._ClientFIO;
                }
                set
                {
                    if ((this._ClientFIO != value))
                    {
                        this.OnClientFIOChanging(value);
                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                        this._ClientFIO = value;
                        this.SendPropertyChanged("ClientFIO");
                        this.OnClientFIOChanged();
                    }
                }
        }
```

it works, but when i try to make partial class- isn't. Can somebody help me with partial class for LINQ generated class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871499/metadatatype-problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, before when it was like this, it wasn't work:

**/Core/Extansions.cs** (Namespace SUPNew.Core) (public partial class Order)
**/Models/SUPNew.dbml** (Namespace SUPNew.Models) (public partial class Order)(generated)

Then, when i replace like this:

**/Models/Extansions.cs** (Namespace SUPNew.Models) (public partial class Order)
**/Models/SUPNew.dbml** (Namespace SUPNew.Models) (public partial class Order)(generated)

it started to work. But, where is the problem? I used all using in everywhere and Import in View.aspx.

I need to make it work like in first example:

**/Core/Extansions.cs** (Namespace SUPNew.Core) (public partial class Order)
**/Models/SUPNew.dbml** (Namespace SUPNew.Models) (public partial class Order)(generated)