# Loading MetaData in Aspnet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm building a project in MVC template using AspNet Core.

I've used Entity Framework and I've scaffolded an existing DB. Now, I want to add some Data Annotations to some class, but I don't wanna edit the class autogenerated by the scaffolding, so I've tried with the Metadata and the overriding of an existing method, the `saveChanges`.

**Users.cs autogenerated by Scaffolding**

```
public partial class Users
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    ...
    // If I have [MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Too short")] here, it works
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**UsersMetadata.cs** (also tried Users.Metadata.cs or else, nothing changed)

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(UsersModelMetaData))]
public partial class Users { }

public class UsersModelMetaData
{
    [MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Too short")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**MyContext : DbContext Class**

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entities = from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                   where e.State == EntityState.Added
                       || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                   select e.Entity;
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {               
    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entity);
        Validator.ValidateObject(entity, validationContext, validateAllProperties: true);
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

So, even if this seems to be the correct solution (i've search all morning), it doesn't work: the problem seems to be that the Data Annotation inside `UsersModelMetaData` aren't read, because if I put the Data Annotation directly in `Users.cs` file, method `saveChanges()` will  throw an exception.

I did found this solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30127682/6070423 <- but it's based on AspNet, and using AspNet Core I cannot use `AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider`.

Any idea how I could resolve this?

Comment: See if this helps (you are not showing your usings, so I don’t know if it is this case): https://stackoverflow.com/a/37375987

Comment: @LuísAntunes in that question, the answer is just to use ModelMetadataType instead of MetadataType, but i'm already using ModelMetadataType.. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after I've asked on the [ASP.Net Core forum](https://forums.asp.net/t/2139531.aspx?Loading%20MetaData%20from%20Partial%20Class%20in%20Aspnet%20Core), thanks to Edward Z answer, I did found a way to make it work.

Basically, instead of creating a partial class with ModelMetadataType, I've created a Class containing all the property that need to be validated (so, I will have a class of this kind for each class created by scaffolding). Something like this.

```
// Class generated by scaffolding
public partial class Users
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

// Class I did create. Notice that the name could be anything
//   but should contain at least "Users", which is the name of
//   the table generated by scaffolding.
// Also notice that isUnique is a Custom Attribute I've wrote.
public class UsersMetaData
    {
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = " too short")]   
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = " too short psw")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [IsUnique(ErrorMessage = "Email already exists")]
        public string Email { get; set; }            
    }
```

After that, I created a mapper which map an instance of the class auto-generated by scaffolding, to the relative class I've craeted. Something like this:

```
public static object MapEntity(object entityInstance)
   {
        var typeEntity = entityInstance.GetType();
        var typeMetaDataEntity = Type.GetType(typeEntity.FullName + "MetaData");

        if (typeMetaDataEntity == null)
            throw new Exception();

        var metaDataEntityInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeMetaDataEntity);

        foreach (var property in typeMetaDataEntity.GetProperties())
        {
            if (typeEntity.GetProperty(property.Name) == null)
                throw new Exception();

            property.SetValue(
                metaDataEntityInstance,
                typeEntity.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(entityInstance));
        }

        return metaDataEntityInstance;
    }
```

Notice that, in the first lines, starting from the type of the instance (which is Users), I retrieve the corresponding class I've created, by adding to that name the string "Metadata". Then, what I do is just to create an instance of the UserMetaData class assigning the same value of the Users instance.

Finally, when this mapper is called? In SaveChanges(), when I do the validation. That's because the validation is made on the UserMetaData class.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var entities = from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                           where e.State == EntityState.Added
                               || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                           select e.Entity;
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                var metaDataEntityInstance = EntityMapper.MapEntity(entity);
                var validationContext = new ValidationContext(metaDataEntityInstance);
                Validator.ValidateObject(
                    metaDataEntityInstance,
                    validationContext,
                    validateAllProperties: true);
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
```

It's kinda tricky, but it all works!